# Reading data into a 2 dimensional array php

Tags: php

I am using `php` and I want to be able place two fields from a query into an array.

I currently have the following which works well:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$array[]=$row['field1'];
}
```

But I can't seem to work out how to read two fields:

```
    $array[][]=$row['field1'] in the first, and  $row['field2'] in the second;
```

So I should get:

```
$array [0][0] as field1
and
$array [0][1] as field2
```

Comment: I think you want to do this: `$array[$row["field1"]][] = $row["field2"];`

Comment: no idea - that is why I am asking for help. I want them separate in the array

Comment: Changed my comment, see my updated one ^

Comment: Do you want "field1" as $array[0] and "field2" as $array[1]?

Comment: Edited the question for clarity @Rizier123 I am afraid that did not work.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array ();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $subarray = array ();
    $subarray[] = $row['field1'];
    $subarray[] = $row['field2'];
    $array[]= $subarray;
}

// more concisely:
$array = array ();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $array[] = array (
        $row['field1'],
        $row['field2']
    );
}
```